# Does Stride require Visual Studio to build the release version of a project?

Tags: stride

I've been reading through the Stride tutorials and manual, and I see on this page:
https://doc.stride3d.net/latest/en/manual/files-and-folders/distribute-a-game.html

... they describe building the release version of your project as a thing you have to go through Visual Studio for, which implies it is impossible for people who can't run visual studio to produce that release version. Is this correct? Is use of visual studio necessary to produce a release build of a project developed in Stride?

Or is there another possible way? For example, would it be possible to achieve the same thing in another IDE, like SharpDevelop?

Comment: I believe you can use Visual Studio Community Edition with Stride, so that shouldn't be a problem?!

Comment: I got the impression that you can use any visual studio to satisfy Stride's dependency, but my question is about building the release version of a project created in Stride. Is Stride basically useless for those of us who can't run visual studio?

Comment: Sorry I missed the point in your question :-( As per the link you provided it seems you need VS! You can ask them in their forum to be sure.

Comment: Stride doesn't have a forum of it's own. Their "Q & A" link leads to this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through investigating this for the last couple of weeks, I have turned up no way to create a build of a Stride project without Visual Studio. So, apparently, the answer is yes, Visual Studio is required for creating builds of Stride Projects, meaning it is not possible to build a Stride project in circumstances where Visual Studio can't be run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dotnet build` in the command line too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/108823)

Comment: @liggiorgio does it not? [From the docs, it *looks* like it's possible to install the .NET SDK and CLI without Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/), which would hypothetically allow one to use this command line example to generate a build without Visual Studio. Does anyone have evidence that this approach does / does not successfully produce Release builds of Stride projects? For the author, thalm, this answer would be clearer if you edited it to provide more detail, or show an example of this successfully building a Stride project.